# Ergodicity on a finite set

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory, statistical-mechanics

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set ($ \#\Omega = n$), how many dynamical systems on $\Omega$ are ergodic?

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: @JohnB oh no, I need to know it for finish another big proof

Comment: Good, so you should start by providing your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @JohnB I think there are (n-1)! because you can find (n-1)! different cycles in a finite set with n elements, what do you think?

Comment: @av_15 When the set is endowed with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra and uniform probability measure the answer is indeed $(n-1)!$. If the measure is arbitrary then it seems ergodic maps can be counted again (in this case $(n-1)!$ will be an upper bound, if the dynamical system is required to be invertible). In the most general case where the $\sigma$-algebra is also not fixed the question of finding an upper bound seems to be subtle.

Comment: Also note that one could consider a map to be defined off a negligible set, and a map to be invertible iff it's invertible off negligible sets.

Comment: Finally perhaps it is better to ask the number of ergodic maps up to measurable measure-preserving isomorphism.